# ansible playbook find/replace acting weird on second run

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have this task that finds 2 lines in sshd_config, and changes them. This works perfectly on the first run, it replaces the src lines with the dest lines.  But if I run it a second time, after the 2 lines in the file are already correct, it appends 2 new lines to the bottom of the file.

I tried adding state: present but it didn't change the behavior.

```
  - name: Configuring sshd_config
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      regexp: "{{ item.src }}"
      state: present
      line: "{{ item.dest }}"
    with_items:
      - { src: "#PrintLastLog yes", dest: "PrintLastLog no" }
      - { src: "#Banner none", dest: "Banner /etc/issue.net" }
```

I was expecting it to not match the src lines and make no changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are getting is the exact expected behaviour. Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html) about the `regexp` parameter when using `state: present`

> When modifying a line the regexp should typically match both the initial state of the line as well as its state after replacement by line to ensure idempotence.

Modifying your task as follow should do the job.

```
  - name: Configuring sshd_config
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      regexp: "{{ item.src }}"
      state: present
      line: "{{ item.dest }}"
    with_items:
      - { src: "^(# *)?PrintLastLog", dest: "PrintLastLog no" }
      - { src: "^(# *)?Banner", dest: "Banner /etc/issue.net" }
```

This will match the commented line (with optionnal spaces after the hash) or the newly modified line.